# Calling a nodeJS application multiple times returns in error

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I'm running the following script via `node index.js`, everything is working fine.

But if I run this via `npm run start` (as it is a nodeJS application), then only for the first call from the browser (localhost:3000) it is working, but reloading the browser gives me `, Remote I/O error`.
Server side I see `Si7021 failed: , Remote I/O error`.

I'm just wondering why I get the expected data for the initial call, but a reload runs into the error.

What am I doing wrong?

**index.js**

```
const Si7021 = require('si7021-sensor')

const getStatus = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const si7021 = new Si7021({ i2cBusNo: 1 });
    await si7021.reset();
    const data = await si7021.readSensorData();
    console.log(data);
    return { data };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Si7021 failed: ${err.message}`);
    return err.message;
  }
}

getStatus()

module.exports = getStatus
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "micro"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "micro": "^9.3.3",
    "si7021-sensor": "0.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: could u show me `package.json`? i wonder `start` field...

Comment: @RobJS Added package.json

Answer (score -1):

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "micro": "^9.3.3",
    "si7021-sensor": "0.0.7"
  }
}
```

Replace ***start*** field with `node .` or `node index.js`.

Comment: I thought of running the app as a micro application